# Webpack + Karma + Angular 1 TypeError: module is not a function

Tags: angularjs, webpack, karma-jasmine, karma-webpack

I am working with legacy code to update the test and build process to fit in with our newer webpack process.

We have an old angular app (v1.7.9) and I have been able to get it building perfectly with webpack, however having some issues when running its test suite (karma + jasmine).

So far my karama config looks like:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ["jasmine"],
    plugins: [
      "karma-jasmine",
      "karma-webpack",
      "karma-chrome-launcher",
      "karma-coverage",
    ],
    files: ["tests/index.test.js"],
    preprocessors: {
      "tests/index.tests.js": ["webpack"],
      "tests/**/*.test.js": ["webpack"],
    },
    reporters: ["progress", "coverage"],
    webpack: { mode: "development" },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: "tests/results/",
      reporters: [
        { type: "html", subdir: "report-html" },
        { type: "lcov", subdir: "report-lcov" },
      ],
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ["ChromeHeadless"],
    singleRun: true,
  });
};
```

My test entry point file looks like

```
//tests/index.test.js
import "angular";
import "angular-mocks";

const testsContext = require.context(".", true, /\.test$/);
testsContext.keys().forEach(testsContext);
```

With an example test looking like:

```
/* global module, inject, SampleController */

describe("SampleController", function() {
  beforeEach(module("MyAngularApp"));

  var controller;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_) {
    controller = _$controller_(SampleController, {});
  }));

  describe("changeQuantity", () => {
    it("should reduce the quantity when the step is negative", () => {
  ...
```

I am also using `plugins: ["angularjs-annotate"]` in my babel config.

The error I am receiving is:

```
"message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nTypeError: module is not a function\n    at Suite.eval (webpack:///./tests/common/mySampleService.test.js?:4:14)\n    at <Jasmine>\n    at Object.eval (webpack:///./tests/common/mySampleService.test.js?:3:1)\n    at eval (webpack:///./tests/common/mySampleService.test.js?:34:30)\n    at Object../tests/common/mySampleService.test.js (tests/index.test.js:305:1)\n    at __webpack_require__ (tests/index.test.js:20:30)\n    at webpackContext (webpack:///./tests_sync_\\.test$?:34:9)\n    at <Jasmine>",
```

Is there something obvious I am missing to get these tests to work? There are a lot of tests, so having to change them would be a nightmare. I am looking to see if there is a configuration in my webpack, karma config or babel I can fix to get these to work.

My suspicion is that it has to something with the angular comments at the top of each test file, and that something to do with those are missing when the tests are running, ie `/* global module, inject, SampleController */`.

*Note: I did not write any of these tests or any of the angular code.*

Comment: So tests were working, you changed something and got error? So what u changed? Also it is always nice idea to run ONE test first.

Comment: The app and tests were previously being built with gulp, and we are now moving towards a webpack build process for this repo. The test fails in the same way if only one test is being run.